# How can I take one large object, use a sub-object of that as the data for multiple instances of the same controller, and keep them both in sync?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

Apologies for the ambiguity of the question :-P

I have a single JavaScript object which contains all my data. And I have a controller which I will use multiple times throughout the application. So the controllers are all working on the same data, the data is added to the application using a service.

To support a read-only/edit mode interaction, I make two copies of the original data source in the service. When the user manipulates data, they are manipulating the edit mode data source. They can then press a button to save the data to the edit mode data source to the read-only mode data source (using angular.copy).

I would also like to have the instances of the controller work on just part of the data source rather than the whole thing.

The behavior I am seeing is angularjs is able to update the parts, keeping them both in sync; but when I press the button to perform the angular.copy, it seems to reassign the variable rather than adjust the value of where it was pointing.

Code below and here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q5ca5quq/1/

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<body>

    <div ng-controller='a_controller as ctrl_1'>
        read_mode_inner = {{ ctrl_1.read_mode_inner }}<br>
        edit_mode_inner = {{ ctrl_1.edit_mode_inner }}<br>
        <br>
        <input ng-model='ctrl_1.edit_mode_inner[0].a'>
    </div>    
    <br><br><br>
    <div ng-controller='a_controller as ctrl_2'>
        read_mode_inner = {{ ctrl_2.read_mode_inner }}<br>
        edit_mode_inner = {{ ctrl_2.edit_mode_inner }}<br>
        <br>
        Change this and press button below <input ng-model='ctrl_2.edit_mode_inner[0].a'> <br>
        <button ng-click='ctrl_2.change()'>Copy edit_mode_inner into read_mode_inner</button>
    </div>





<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

    angular.module('app',[])
    .factory('DataService', [function() {
        data = {
            xx : [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}],
            yy : [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
        }

        return {
            read_mode : data,
            edit_mode : angular.copy(data)
        }
    }])
    .controller('a_controller', ['DataService', function(DataService) {
        var self = this;
        window.s = self; // For debugging

        self.read_mode = DataService.read_mode;
        self.edit_mode = DataService.edit_mode;

        self.read_mode_inner = self.read_mode.xx;
        self.edit_mode_inner = self.edit_mode.xx;

        self.change = function(){
            self.read_mode_inner = angular.copy(self.edit_mode_inner);
        }

    }]);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so to clarify, what would you like to happen in your fiddle after the button is pressed?

Comment: It appears to be working properly on my system, lest I misunderstood..  You want ctrl1's `read_mode_inner` to be different from that of ctrl2, right?

Comment: No, I actually want them to be the same. So if you adjust the value in the second input field, it updates edit_mode_inner for both ctrl1 and ctrl2. Which is good. Then when the button is pressed, it overwrites read_mode_inner for ctrl2 with the edit_mode data. I expected the same change to happen to ctrl1's data when the button was pressed. To put it another way, I want the user to be able to hit a button in either controller and it updates both controllers data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/q5ca5quq/2/

You can share data between controllers using a service, but if you want all controller instances to update every time the value in service is changed, you'll need something like $watch inside your controller:

```
$scope.change = function(){
    DataService.read_mode.xx = angular.copy($scope.edit_mode_inner);
}

$scope.$watch(function(){return DataService}, function(dataService){
    $scope.read_mode_inner = dataService.read_mode.xx;
}, true);
```

For this to work you need to use angular $scope instead of this/self reference. Notice how using $scope also simplified angular notation in HTML. You don't need to name controllers separately:

instead of:

```
<div ng-controller='a_controller as ctrl_1'>
    read_mode_inner = {{ ctrl_1.read_mode_inner }}<br>
    edit_mode_inner = {{ ctrl_1.edit_mode_inner }}<br>
</div>
```

You only have to:

```
<div ng-controller='a_controller'>
    read_mode_inner = {{ read_mode_inner }}<br>
    edit_mode_inner = {{ edit_mode_inner }}<br>
</div>
```

because $scope takes care of the rest.